# Flutter: Force modalBottomSheet to only close on button click

Tags: flutter, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I am using a modalBottomSheet to store my user's settings profile. I want to perform a firebase operation on close of the bottom sheet. Is there a way to disable all modalBottomSheet gestures to force the sheet to only close on an icon onTap operation? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `isDismissible` and `enableDrag` to `false`.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isDismissible: false,
    enableDrag: false,
    builder: (context) => BottomSheetWidget(),
);
```

Comment: Fantastic Jigar. Thanks very much!